# How to quickly transform large-scale data on the multi-nodes using apache-spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark. So I am struggling to train myself in order to get familiar with the spark and distributed systems by following some tutorials and small tasks.
Among some tasks, below is one that have me ask a questions here to find the better solution.

Below is my sample data.

```
EEL    A    CAT    LOC1    EEX    13|42|45|67
EEL    A    CAT    LOC2    EEX    24|32
....
```

My goal is to transform above data as below.

```
EEL    A    CAT    LOC1    EEX    13
EEL    A    CAT    LOC1    EEX    42
EEL    A    CAT    LOC1    EEX    45
EEL    A    CAT    LOC1    EEX    67
EEL    A    CAT    LOC2    EEX    24
EEL    A    CAT    LOC2    EEX    32
```

I made my codes as below and it worked well for the data size of under 10MB. However, if I input a large data set (more than 3GB), it took about 10~15mins to finish on the multi-nodes platform.

Note that I am using one spark-master node and four-data nodes which have 16-cores and 16GB memory size respectively.

Considering my computer specifications, I think that this simple transformation tasks shouldn't take too much time and I also think that there is a more efficient way to reduce the running time.

I know that spark is based on the in-memory systems and I strongly believe that it helps me handles such an iterative and simple tasks easily,but the results looked a little bit disappointed to me.

Below is my full code. I skipped the detailed explanation because it is very straightforward.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import scala.Tuple2;


public class DataTransformation {
    public static JavaRDD<String> DataTransformation_V01(String input,JavaSparkContext sc){
        JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(input);

        JavaRDD<String> line = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterator<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
                return Arrays.asList(s.split("\n")).iterator();
            }
        });


        JavaRDD<String> newLine = line.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
            public Iterator<String> call(String s) throws Exception {
                List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> ls = Arrays.asList(s.split("\t"));

                String values = ls.get(ls.size()-1);
                List<String> value = Arrays.asList(values.split("\\|"));

                for(int i=0;i<value.size();++i){
                    String ns = ls.get(0)+"\t"+ls.get(1)+"\t"+ls.get(2)+"\t"+ls.get(3)+"\t"+ls.get(4)+"\t"+ls.get(5);
                    ns = ns + "\t" + value.get(i);
                    ret.add(ns);
                }
                return ret.iterator();
            }
        });
        return newLine;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String inputFile = args[0];
        String outputFile = args[1];
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Data Transformation")
                .set("spark.serializer","org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        JavaPairRDD<String,String> result = DataTransformation_V01(inputFile,sc);

        System.out.println(result.count());
        result.saveAsTextFile(outputFile);

        sc.stop();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Dataframes API instead of RDD for this computation. The following snippet (using scala brevity) would achieve your requirement.

```
scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> val df  = sc.textFile("/user/test/files/spark_test.txt").map(_.split(',')).map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5))).toDF("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5","c6")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c1: string, c2: string, c3: string, c4: string, c5: string, c6: string]

scala> df.explode("c6","c7")((x:String) => x.split('|')).drop("c6").show()
{"level": "INFO ", "timestamp": "2017-01-30 01:13:09,138", "classname": "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader", "body": "Loaded native gpl library"}
{"level": "INFO ", "timestamp": "2017-01-30 01:13:09,141", "classname": "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec", "body": "Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 2cedc48fab9e2e10a84b909b4c198053ff379ac7]"}
+---+---+---+----+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|  c4| c5| c7|
+---+---+---+----+---+---+
|EEL|  A|CAT|LOC1|EEX| 13|
|EEL|  A|CAT|LOC1|EEX| 42|
|EEL|  A|CAT|LOC1|EEX| 45|
|EEL|  A|CAT|LOC1|EEX| 67|
|EEL|  A|CAT|LOC2|EEX| 24|
|EEL|  A|CAT|LOC2|EEX| 32|
+---+---+---+----+---+---+
```

I have assumed you here that we have csv file as shown below

```
EEL,A,CAT,LOC1,EEX,13|42|45|67
EEL,A,CAT,LOC2,EEX,24|32
```

Dataframes are more performant than RDD since it can leverage Catalyst optimizer and avoid JVM Object serialization/deserialization and the associated GC overhead.
more details over [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html).

Other obvious performance considerations are using a parquet file instead of plain text files. Since parquet files are columnar and sports better compression.. this would results in significant reduction on IO. Addtionally you can read a parquet file directly into a dataframe and skip the expensive RDD phase completely.